# Googleplay: About Upgrade your app signing key in App signing

Tags: android, apk-signing

In the App signing of GooglePlay console, I can upgrade my App signing key. I have one question about this.

For example, my App use cert A to sign the APK. Then I upgrade the cert B in the Googleplay console. From the downloaded APK in the App Bundle Explorer, I can see they use APK v3.1 sign, so the A and B certificates both are used.

But what would happen if I upgrade again with certificate C AFTER B been upgraded? Would the apk signed with AC or BC using V3.1 sign? I cannot try this because this certificate upgrade can only be done once annually. Anyone tried this?